# CoreData: error: (778) I/O error for database ? How to handle this error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I'm getting a Core data error when **my app is in open state with lock screen** mode.

My code:

```
func savePesistenceContext() {
     //try! self.dataStack.mainContext.save()
     do {
           try self.dataStack.mainContext.save()
        } catch {
          let nserror = error as NSError
          debugPrint("savePesistenceContext", nserror)
        }
}
```

Error:

```
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x280697540> , I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6EBC7CD6-9299-431A-A24A-1F6FA86792BD/Documents/Coral.sqlite.  SQLite error code:778, 'disk I/O error' with userInfo of {
    NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6EBC7CD6-9299-431A-A24A-1F6FA86792BD/Documents/Coral.sqlite";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 778;
}

CoreData: error: (778) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6EBC7CD6-9299-431A-A24A-1F6FA86792BD/Documents/Coral.sqlite.  SQLite error code:778, 'disk I/O error'


Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “Coral.sqlite” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9AB16F39-8933-4A75-AB6A-59CBBCC42A4F/Documents/Coral.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=23}
```

When will this error come and how can we resolve this error?

Comment: Do yo have some kind of data protection on?

Comment: @lorem ipsum, some kind of data protection on means. Can you explain to me what exactly?

Comment: @lorem ipsum, Hi we are using EncryptedCoreData

Comment: That’s is likely why. I wouldn’t expect to be able to write to a database that is locked. You likely need to cache it somewhere that isn’t encrypted and when the app is active again write it to CoreData.

Comment: @lorem ipsum, can you please explain briefly or please answer for me.

Comment: @lorem ipsum, How to put in unlock state for a few seconds and how to reopen core data when user unlocked.

Comment: I couldn’t tell you exactly how to overcome it I don’t use EncryptedCoreData. I only speak from experience in other areas that use encryption. When the phone is locked you cannot write to the encrypted part. As far as caching. I would say put it in a file and when your scene returns to the active state check that file for contents and transfer any data to core data